# Group values by date in a generated timeseries

Tags: group-by, time-series, amazon-redshift

I have a table called 'daily_budgets':

```
+----+------------+----------+--------------+
| id | start_date | end_date | daily_budget |
+----+------------+----------+--------------+
| 1  | 25/04/18   | 29/04/18 | 500          |
+----+------------+----------+--------------+
| 2  | 26/04/18   | 27/04/18 | 1000         |
+----+------------+----------+--------------+
```

that shows the daily budget that an item has between a designated timeframe (start_date - end_date).

Then I have another one called 'year_2018' where I have generated a time_series with all the dates for 2018:

```
+----------+
| date     |
+----------+
| 01/01/18 |
+----------+
| 02/01/18 |
+----------+
| 03/01/18 |
+----------+
| 04/01/18 |
+----------+
| 05/01/18 |
+----------+
etc.
```

Now I just want to join those two tables so that I get total daily_budget grouped by date. The first date in that resulting table should be the minimum start_date that there is in table 'daily_budgets'.

```
+----------+--------------+
| date     | daily_budget |
+----------+--------------+
| 25/04/18 | 500          |
+----------+--------------+
| 26/04/18 | 1500         |
+----------+--------------+
| 27/04/18 | 1500         |
+----------+--------------+
| 28/04/18 | 500          |
+----------+--------------+
| 29/04/18 | 500          |
+----------+--------------+
```

Thanks very much for the help!

I am using: PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.2058

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the two tables on the condition of the date from your calendar table being in between (inclusive) of the start and end budget dates.  Then aggregate by date to generate the totals.

```
SELECT
    c.date,
    SUM(daily_budget) AS daily_budget
FROM year_2018 c
INNER JOIN daily_budgets db
    ON c.date BETWEEN db.start_date AND db.end_date
GROUP BY
    c.date;
```

Note that I use an inner join here, which will have the effect of filtering off any dates from the calendar table which do not appear in at least one record in the budget table.  This should enforce that the earliest date you see reported is also the earliest date in the budget table.

Comment: thanks very much @Tim Biegeleisen — works perfect :-)